# jQuery ui sortable multiple column width elements

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to make three columns of lists that are connected by the jquery sortable widget, this is easy. Now the difficult part: I want some elements to have the width of two or three columns.

Does anyone have an idea where to start? Would an other library be more suitable?

Gr. Tosh

Comment: Are you looking to have the multi-column elements stretch over the other columns and effect them as well?